# Find the instance when discrete time model has a specific value

Tags: electrical-engineering, control-engineering, control-theory

I have the following model:
$$ x[k+1] = Ax[k] + Bu[k]$$
$$ y[k]   = x[k] $$
where $x \in \mathbb{R} $ is the state, $A \in \mathbb{R}$, $u \in \mathbb{R}^4$ are the inputs and $B \in \mathbb{R}^4$ and $y[k]$ is the output.

From theory this can be solved using:
$$ y[k] = A^k x[0] + \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} A^{k-1-i}Bu[i]$$

How can I find the time instance $k$ when $y[k]$ has a specific value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on your initial value and your input.

For specific initial values and inputs there are easy solutions, but in general I think the fastest way is to let the computer solve this for you.
So crank up your matlab / python / mathematica / excel / other tool of choice
and let the brute force of computation serve you.

Comment: Yeah I thought so, I wish there was a cleaner way

Comment: @Marc The reason why, in general, you can't solve for $k$, is because for a given input and initial condition the output $y$ might only be able to obtain values from a fixed (finite) set of values. For example $x[0]=0$, $u[k]=\vec{0}$, can only obtain $y[k]=0$.